# Can't get the image link

Tags: php, image

So I can't insert images. I keep getting the following error.

> "Notice: Undefined index: uploaded"

I can't get the image link!
Uploaded is the name of the button type=file (Upload images)

```
<?php     
$host="localhost"; // Nome do host onde esta o banco de dados. Padrão ‘localhost’ 
$usuario="root"; // Usuário do Mysql. Padrão ‘root’
$senha=""; // Senha do Mysql 
$db ="centro"; // Nome da Database 
$tabela="usuarios"; // Nome da tabela

//connecta ao servidor
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("$host", "$usuario", "$senha")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db($mysqli,$db)or die("cannot select DB");

if(isset($_POST["upload"]))
{
  //HERE!!!!!!!     

  $d="imagens/" . $_FILES["uploaded"]["name"];
  if($_FILES["uploaded"]["type"]=="image/jpeg")
  {
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploaded"]["tmp_name"],$d))
    {
      echo '<img style="width:50px;height:50px;" src="'. $d . '" >';
    }
  }
  $titulo=$_POST['titulo'];
  $mensagem=$_POST['mensagem'];
  $ano=$_POST['ano'];
  $mes=$_POST['mes'];
  $dia=$_POST['dia'];
  $link=$d;
}
else
{
  echo "So imagens JPG.";
  $titulo=" ";
  $mensagem=" ";
  $ano=0;
  $mes=0;
  $dia=0;
  $link=" ";
}

$query = "INSERT INTO imagens(titulo,mensagem,dia,mes,ano,link) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stat = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stat->bind_param('ssiiis',$titulo,$mensagem,$dia,$mes,$ano,$link);

if ($stat->execute() && $stat->affected_rows>0)
{
  echo "<div>Foi inserida uma imagem!</div>";
}
$stat->close();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: check your form tag and add enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: Please post your html

Comment: it works, thx man!!! @devpro

Comment: btw `if($_FILES["uploaded"]["type"]=="image/jpeg")` this is extremly dangerous mime type check method you should use server side controls like [`finfo_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting:

> Notice: Undefined index: uploaded

For this notice check your HTML Form and

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

**Example:**

```
 <form action="youraction" method="yourMethod" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

[HTML  enctype Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp)